# curl - not working properly inside shell script program

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I wrote a shell script with the following set of commands.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
curl -v http://api.myapi.com/API/firstApi #1
curl -v http://api.myapi.com/API/secondApi #2
echo "Success"
```

The second curl call(#2) will take almost 1 minute to finish the process. When I run this command from commandline it is working fine. Taking almost 1 minute and printing the response. But when I execute it from a shell script, it exits very fast, the expected process is not happening in the backend, but printing the response. I don't have any clue why it is happening. I tried `&&`, but not working.

Any clue on this?

Comment: When you test your command in the command-line, is it preceded by the same actions (reloading and restarting apache, then calling firstApi) ? Also, I find doubtful that a `curl -v` call wouldn't output anything. You might want to try to make this call alone in a bash script (or remove the output of other commands in your current script) and come back to post the output of your `curl` command

Comment: Also make sure you haven't a trailing `&` in your url. If you have, enclose your url in single-quotes (which you should probably do anyway).

Comment: @Aaron >>is it preceded by the same actions (restarting apache, then calling firstApi) ?<< **Yes**. I tried without -v option also. There is no trailing `&`.

Comment: `-v` shouldn't change the behavior, it just makes `curl` print verbose information (which you will probably want to avoid in your script once it works as intended). However, it is verbose enough that even a call to an incorrect url, or to a page with no content should print plenty information, which you should post here. Remove the output of other commands ( `1,2&> /dev/null`) if you don't know what the output of the problematic `curl` command is

Comment: Of course this doesn't exclude that your `curl` command might not be executed at all, which would probably be explained by a syntax error in the previous line, but from your code (which I suppose you edited before posting), nothing seems to point this out

Comment: @Aaron I kept the `#2` API call in a different file and called the script from the original one. Now it is working fine. Is this the only way it supposes to work?

Comment: No, what you posted should work, I just can't tell what's wrong from the code you posted. I guess that's because you posted an example code with the URLs replaced and the problem stems from the real URLs you use. You might want to check your code with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), it would probably find out such problems without you having to disclose the URLs you're calling (if you're paranoid install their offline tool, otherwise I suppose the website has a decent privacy policy)